Get a URL from Edge browser
I have an Edge browser open with one tab. I want to get the URL of the webpage into a variable in excel so I can create a hyperlink to it.  I asked this question a couple years ago and received an answer that only works once.  If I then navigate to a different webpage and run the macro, it pulls up the URL of the previous page, not the open one.
Function TryGetUrl(ByRef outUrl As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo errExit
    
    ' change to "Chrome" if desired
    AppActivate "Edge", True
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
    
    Application.SendKeys "^l^c", True
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
    
    AppActivate Application.Caption
    
    ' needs a reference to the 'Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library'
    With New MSForms.DataObject
        .GetFromClipboard
        outUrl = .GetText
    End With
    
    TryGetUrl = True
    Exit Function
errExit:
End Function

